# Vaadin ComboBox debounce change

Tags: combobox, vaadin-flow, debouncing

I want to do ComboBox more faster when answer by filtering string. How to change debounce parameter for ComboBox of Vaadin Flow 14 ?

My worries about debounce is started from there:

https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/518

https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/blob/master/vaadin-combo-box-flow-parent/vaadin-combo-box-flow/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/frontend/comboBoxConnector.js#L97-L99

Please look at this example:
https://github.com/lanmaster/ping-component-demo

And video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3l2iXAhQzQ

Maybe there is no problem with debounce at all, but all i need is to faster UI responsibility with ComboBox (faster reload filtered data) with minimal delays on each char entered.

Comment: The ComboBox is fast. How do you set the items?

Comment: I set as CallbackDataProvider and as simple "setItems()". Look at the example, i edited question.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I don't see any way to change this behavoir.